# Why Doesn't This PHP Download Script Work?

Tags: php, mysql, download

Here is a simple script I have written to limit downloads for users to one at a time (IE if they are downloading a file then they cannot download another one until they cancel the current download or it finishes).

```
ignore_user_abort(true);

$local_file = $_GET['filename'];
$download_file = explode("/", $local_file);
$download_file = $download_file[count($download_file) -1];

// set the download rate limit (value is in kilobytes per second
$download_rate = 100;
if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file)) {
    $ip = visitor_ip();
    if(!are_downloading($ip)) {
        header('Cache-control: private');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
        header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download_file);

        flush();

        $file = fopen($local_file, "r");
        log_downloader($ip);

        while(!feof($file)) {
            if (!connection_aborted()) {
            // send the current file part to the browser
            print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));
            // flush the content to the browser
            flush();
            // sleep one second
            sleep(1);
        } else {
            break;
            }
        }

        clear_downloader($ip);      
        fclose($file);
    } else {
        die('<span style="color:#DDDDDD">Due to server limitations you may only download one file at a time. Please cancel or wait for your current download to finish before trying again. Click <a href="/simfiles">here</a> to return.</span>');
    }
} else {
    die('Error: The file '.$local_file.' does not exist!');
}

function visitor_ip() { 
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $TheIp=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else $TheIp=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    return trim($TheIp);
}

function are_downloading($ip) {
    $query = "select * from downloaders where ip_addr='$ip'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    return $num_rows > 0; 
}

function log_downloader($ip) {
    $query = "insert into downloaders (ip_addr) values ('$ip')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}

function clear_downloader($ip) {
    $query = "delete from downloaders where ip_addr='$ip'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

When I test it out, it works fine, but for a lot of people, their IP never gets cleared out of the database - even when they have finished downloading/cancelled a file. Why don't the IPs get deleted?

Comment: This is a bad idea because of NAT. I'd use their PHP session ID instead of their IP to identify them, which is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: This script is extremely insecure.  You are letting users download whatever they want off your hard drive, including the source code to your applications, possibly passwords, etc.  You're also wide open to SQL injection attacks, since you are trusting the request headers for the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` values and what not, and not escaping anything before using it in a database.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid SQL injection problems, and validate the files you're allowing users to download to make sure they are in the directory you expect.

Comment: There's more stuff going on to deal with the issues you mentioned - this is just the part of the script causing problems.

Comment: @ChunkyBaconPlz could you please elaborate on how you would do this?

Comment: @CameronBall Instead of using the unreliable (and as Brad pointed out, sometimes insecure) $_SERVER variable array, use the session ID that PHP generates for each user: `$sess_id = session_id();`. Then insert `$sess_id` in your database as the unique identifier instead of their IP. An IP address is a terrible thing to use if you want to uniquely identify someone.

Comment: @ChunkyBaconPlz session_id() is empty when I call it.

Comment: @CameronBall Make sure you use session_start(); at the start of your PHP pages.

Comment: @ChunkyBaconPlz that seems to be working, however now the script just hangs when a user tries to download two files at once, instead of dieing and displaying the message. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: @CameronBall Add some `echo` or `syslog()` calls for debugging so you can tell exactly where it hangs.

Comment: It was because PHP puts a lock on session data. So when they try download another file the script must wait for the previous file to finish before it can read session data. Calling session_write_close() straight after reading the session id solved it. I'll just have to wait now and see if session ids get stuck in the DB.

Comment: OK nope, it still doesn't work. IDs are getting stuck in there - so the issue was obviously not the IP address stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that with big downloads the MySQL connection went away, I simply had to reconnect in the clear_downloader function and now it works fine.